# comparing two floating numbers in Ruby, giving false

Tags: ruby

I have two numbers:
balance1 = 0.253164557e-4 (which would give 0.0000253164557)
balance2 = 0.00002531

now when I compare then in ruby like:
`balance1  == balance2` , it gives false due to precision issue

but my requirement consider them to be equal, suggest ways to do this

Comment: _"my requirement consider them to be equal"_ – what are your exact requirements?

Comment: Do it like in mathematics: If you can not reasonably use _x=y_ for equality, test for _|x-y|<δ_, i.e. take the absolute value of the difference between the numbers and see whether it is smaller than a certain delta.

Comment: First you need to round numbers to the desired (required) precision (it can be 8 digits after the dot, looking at your question) then compare numbers with the delta.

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point numbers are not suitable for exact comparison. Often, two numbers that should be equal are actually slightly different. One way to compare two floating-point numbers is by using a delta value. You can check if the absolute difference between the two numbers is less than or equal to the delta value. For example: (expected_float - actual_float).abs <= delta

Comment: The question isn't about floating-point errors. The OP's numbers are known to be different. (your solution works nonetheless)

Comment: All right I just see